# extracting a parameter from a probability

Tags: statistics

There are $1000$ kids out of which $A$ kids are redheaded. $40$ kids are randomly chosen.

What does A need to be so that the probability of getting $3$ redheaded kids in the group is lower than $0.1$?

I tried defining a hypergeometric rv H that $HG(1000,A,40)<0.1$ but I get an equation that I don't know how to compute, I know for a fact that there's a solution that can be reached by hand for this problem. Would love to get some help as to whether my approach is correct and how to solve this problem. thank you.

Comment: Are you sampling with or without replacement? Also, are you referring to the probability of getting *exactly* three red-headed kids, or *at least* three red-headed kids?

Comment: exactly three, I didn't quite understand the first question, what sampling and what replacement?

Comment: @MatthewPilling I think the question suggests "without replacement", i.e. the $40$ are $40$ different kids

Comment: Exactly I agree